# How do i write this piece of python code in php?

Tags: php, python, urllib2

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson'
values = {'data': [{'text': 'I love Titanic.'}, {'text': 'I hate Titanic.'}]}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
page = response.read()
```

How do i write this in php? I know theres urlencode for php but Is there a function that lets me open a url by passing the url and the encoded values like the python code above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is *not* a code translation service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself** and then if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working**.

Answer (score 2):

good, you can use something like this, if:

```
$url = 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson?';
$data = array (
        'data' => urlencode('I love Titanic.'),
        'text' => urlencode('I hate Titanic.')
    );

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $url .= $key . '=' . $value . "&";
}

$curl = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
```

You can also use the POST method and *n* other things..

I suggest you try to see more information about CURL: http://br.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson';
$values = {'data': [{'text': 'I love Titanic.'}, {'text': 'I hate Titanic.'}]};
$response = http_post_fields(urlencode($url),json_decode($values,true));
?>
```